# Find and replace 100 in a string

Tags: c#

I have a string that could be anything like

100100001
or
101000

I need to find a way to remove the 100 until it's reduced to it's simplest form

```
100100001 ==> 001
101000    ==> empty
```

Can't use 3rd party tools
must only use

```
 System
System.Collections.Generic
System.IO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a simple loop, checking if the string contains the value an if it does, replace it with blank:

```
var input = "101000";

while(input.Contains("100"))
{
    input = input.Replace("100", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use recursion, something like this:

```
public string Reduce(string s)
{
    return s.Contains("100") ? Reduce(s.Replace("100", string.Empty)) : s;
}
```